# Reason for irregular verb conjugation

Tags: verb, conjugation

For some verbs, such as *essen*, the conjugations for *du* and *er, sie, es* are irregular. Instead of following the pattern and becoming *esst*, the vowel is changed to *i*, making it *isst*. Another example is *fahren* which becomes *fährst* and *fährt* respectively.

What is the origin of this peculiar behavior and is there an easier way to know which verbs change other than just remembering them?

Comment: I'm afraid you're stuck with memorizing - there is no clear rule that I'm aware of, and these things tend to change over time

Comment: Each word has its own history. You can hardly answer this question. Here are some links (in German) that might help you: [starke-verben-ablautreihen-konjugation](http://www.belleslettres.eu/print/starke-verben-ablautreihen-konjugation-v3.pdf), [Wie beugt man starke Verben?](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/starke-verben-ablautreihen-konjugation.php), [Warum gibt es im Deutsch
starke und schwache Verben?](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/verb-beugung-konjugation.php)

Comment: @Em1: You are right: Each word has its own history. However, sometimes/often there are patterns that can help you understand why things are as they are and memorize them. (In my opinion, the worst thing that you can do to students/learners is to say: everything irregular, you have to learn it by heart.)

Comment: Yes, an old teacher of mine in the Irish language pointed out that it is in fact the most common verbs that will have the most variation and irregularity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two main classes in German verb conjugation: **Strong verbs** are verbs that form their past tense with ablaut (*s**i**ngen - s**a**ng - ges**u**ngen*); **weak verbs** are verbs that form their past tense with a dental suffix (*leben - leb**t**e - geleb**t***).

The phenomenon that you describe (vowel change in present singular) is primarily one that occurs in **strong verb** conjugation. It can be explained by looking at the verb endings of Old High German strong verbs in present tense:

> *infinitive:* werf**an**
>   *1st person singular:* ih wirf**u**
>   *2nd person singular:* dû wirf**is**
>   *3rd person singular:* er wirf**it**
>   *1st person plural:* wir werf**emês**/werf**ên**
>   *2nd person plural:* ir werf**et**
>   *3rd person plural:* sie werf**ent**

As you can see, the OHG present tense endings in singular for strong verbs are **-u/-is/-it**. Now, we can distinguish two sub-phenomena:

**e/i change:** In this case the vowel preceding the ending is **e** as seen in *w**e**rf-*. The vowels **u** and **i** of the ending are close vowels. They "pull" the preceding vowel **e** up (assimilation). If you move along the ["Vokaltrapez"/vowel trapecium](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vokaltrapez) starting at **e** moving towards the close vowels you end up at **i**. That's why the singular forms have an **i** and not an **e**.
In later times, the 1st person singular moved back to the **e** sound. Additionally, the verb endings got simplified a bit but their influence on the preceding vowel remained. So, today we have:

> *infinitive:* werfen
>   *1st person singular:* ich werfe
>   *2nd person singular:* du w**i**rfst
>   *3rd person singular:* er w**i**rft
>   *1st person plural:* wir werfen
>   *2nd person plural:* ihr werft
>   *3rd person plural:* sie werfen

**Umlaut**: The second sub-phenomenon is umlaut in 2nd and 3rd person singular. The sound **i** of the verb ending is a front vowel. If it is preceded by a non-front vowel like **a**, **o** or **au** this vowel is fronted by assimilation. An **a** getting fronted is an **ä** (*f**a**hren - du f**ä**hrst*), an **o** getting fronted is an **ö** (*st**o**ßen - du st**ö**ßt*) and an **au** getting fronted is an **äu** (*s**au**fen - du s**äu**fst*). The **u** of the 1st person ending does not yield a fronting. Thus the conjugation of (present-day) **fahren** is

> *infinitive:* fahren
>   *1st person singular:* ich fahre
>   *2nd person singular:* du f**ä**hrst
>   *3rd person singular:* er f**ä**hrt
>   *1st person plural:* wir fahren
>   *2nd person plural:* ihr fahrt
>   *3rd person plural:* sie fahren

---

- These two phenomena are not found regularly with weak verbs because (in simple terms) weak verbs had different verb endings than strong verbs.
- Sometimes the **i** of **e/i change** becomes a long one that is written **ie** (*l**e**sen - du l**ie**st*)
- Sometimes the **e** of **e/i change** has become an **ä** or **ö** (*geb**ä**ren - du geb**ie**rst*; *erl**ö**schen - du erl**i**schst*)
- Sometimes there is no umlaut to avoid an ambiguity (*s**au**gen - du s**au**gst* instead of *du s**äu**gst* since there is a verb *säugen*).

---

To answer your question about how to know which verbs show this phenomenon: If you know that a verb is a strong one, then you can assume that there is **e/i change** or **umlaut** in 2nd/3rd person singular. You have only to learn by heart those cases where something unexpected happens.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same concept as in the English or French languages, some verbs just are different. Usually the concerned verbs are **more commonly used** in language and/or **of older origin**.

Examples:

> *German*:
>
> Sein: Ich **bin**, Du **bist**, Er **ist**, Wir **sind**, Ihr **seid**, Sie **sind**
>
> *English*:
>
> To be: I **am**, You **are**, He **is**, We **are**, You **are**, They **are**
>
> *French*:
>
> être: Je **suis**, Tu **es**, Il **est**, Nous **sommes**, Vous **êtes**, Ils **sont**

Answer (score 2):

I remember several reasons:

- ancient methods to express grammatical functions (inflection), which remained within the language, but are not productive anymore (singen, sang, gesungen vs. verlinken, verlinkte, verlinkt)
- highly productive words such as *sein*, which are used very often and are prone to change
- phenomena such as the Präteritopräsentia, where preterite forms became present. A similar example is „möchten“, which people do not recognise as Konjunktiv II anymore
- „wrong” strong inflection, such as schneien - schnie - geschnien, winken - winkte - gewunken; preisen - pries - gepriesen (from preisen, preiste, gepreist)
- Konjunktiv II has problems in Verbs such as beginnen (begönne or begänne?); this would have been easier in Old or Middle High German, since plural inflection was different